# Is there any Biblical answers to what condition our bodies will be in after the resurrection?

Tags: resurrection, human-body, resurrection-body

I hear a lot of people claiming that our bodies will return to the state where we were at our best. Like for example, a woman with bruises from abuse won't have her bruises. Is there a Biblical basis for this, or is this just a common 'misconception?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scriptures tell us that in the resurrection we will be "changed" to be "like the angels" with spiritual bodies that are imperishable and powerful:

[Luke 20:34-36 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2020%3A34-36&version=NIV)

> <sup>34</sup> Jesus replied, “The people of this age marry and are given in marriage. <sup>35</sup> But those who are considered worthy of taking part in the age to come and in the resurrection from the dead will neither marry nor be given in marriage, <sup>36</sup> and they can no longer die; for they are like the angels. They are God’s children, since they are children of the resurrection.

[1 Corinthians 15:35-58 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20cor%2015%3A35-58&version=NIV)

> **The Resurrection Body**
>
> <sup>35</sup> But someone will ask, “How are the dead raised? With what kind of body will they come?” <sup>36</sup> How foolish! What you sow does not come to life unless it dies. <sup>37</sup> When you sow, you do not plant the body that will be, but just a seed, perhaps of wheat or of something else. <sup>38</sup> But God gives it a body as he has determined, and to each kind of seed he gives its own body. <sup>39</sup> Not all flesh is the same: People have one kind of flesh, animals have another, birds another and fish another. <sup>40</sup> There are also heavenly bodies and there are earthly bodies; but the splendor of the heavenly bodies is one kind, and the splendor of the earthly bodies is another. <sup>41</sup> The sun has one kind of splendor, the moon another and the stars another; and star differs from star in splendor.
>
> <sup>42</sup> So will it be with the resurrection of the dead. The body that is sown is perishable, it is raised imperishable; <sup>43</sup> it is sown in dishonor, it is raised in glory; it is sown in weakness, it is raised in power; <sup>44</sup> it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body.
>
> If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body. <sup>45</sup> So it is written: “The first man Adam became a living being”; the last Adam, a life-giving spirit. <sup>46</sup> The spiritual did not come first, but the natural, and after that the spiritual. <sup>47</sup> The first man was of the dust of the earth; the second man is of heaven. <sup>48</sup> As was the earthly man, so are those who are of the earth; and as is the heavenly man, so also are those who are of heaven. <sup>49</sup> And just as we have borne the image of the earthly man, so shall we bear the image of the heavenly man.
>
> <sup>50</sup> I declare to you, brothers and sisters, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable. <sup>51</sup> Listen, I tell you a mystery: We will not all sleep, but we will all be changed— <sup>52</sup> in a flash, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, the dead will be raised imperishable, and we will be changed. <sup>53</sup> For the perishable must clothe itself with the imperishable, and the mortal with immortality. <sup>54</sup> When the perishable has been clothed with the imperishable, and the mortal with immortality, then the saying that is written will come true: “Death has been swallowed up in victory.”
>
> <sup>55</sup> 
>   “Where, O death, is your victory?
>       Where, O death, is your sting?”
>
> <sup>56</sup> The sting of death is sin, and the power of sin is the law. <sup>57</sup> But thanks be to God! He gives us the victory through our Lord Jesus Christ.
>
> <sup>58</sup> Therefore, my dear brothers and sisters, stand firm. Let nothing move you. Always give yourselves fully to the work of the Lord, because you know that your labor in the Lord is not in vain.

From this, it seems that our bodies will **not** be merely returned to the state when we were at our best, but will become something qualitatively better.

Answer (score 1):

When the Word says that when we see Him we shall be like Him, we can understand 1 John 3:2 to be saying a number of things.  I take it 
to be an allusion to things already written about our *resurrection body*.

### John 20:19, 26-28

> 19 Then the same day at evening, being the first day of the week, when
>   the doors were shut where the disciples were assembled for fear of the
>   Jews, came Jesus and stood in the midst, and saith unto them, Peace be
>   unto you.
>   26 And after eight days again his disciples were within, and
>   Thomas with them: then came Jesus, the doors being shut, and stood in
>   the midst, and said, Peace be unto you. 27 Then saith he to Thomas,
>   Reach hither thy finger, and behold my hands; and reach hither thy
>   hand, and thrust it into my side: and be not faithless, but believing.
>   28 And Thomas answered and said unto him, My Lord and my God.

What this can be taken to mean is that our bodies might be able to walk through walls at the least.  Solid matter such as walls and 
doors will be of no consequence to us.  But, then do they stay in a transmogrified, ghostly state with no material substance?
No, we see that Thomas was able to touch Jesus and feel His nail scarred hands.  The event happened twice while the room was shut and 
likely locked.

### Luke 24:42

> And they gave him a piece of a broiled fish, and of an honeycomb.

### Hebrews 2:5-9

> 5 For unto the angels hath he not put in subjection the world to come, whereof we speak.
>   6 But one in a certain place testified, saying, What is man, that thou art mindful of him? or the son of man that thou visitest him?
>   7 Thou madest him a little lower than the angels; thou crownedst him with glory and honour, and didst set him over the works of thy hands:
>   8 Thou hast put all things in subjection under his feet. For in that he put all in subjection under him, he left nothing that is not put under him. But now we see not yet all things put under him.
>   9 But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels for the suffering of death, crowned with glory and honour; that he by the grace of God should taste death for every man.

lastly 
Luke 24:13-35
Which speaks of Jesus' encounter with two of His disciples on the road to Emmaus.
The fail to recognize Him, and also fail to recognize His voice.  It's only later on that they recognize one of His mannerisms. His unique way of blessing the bread, reminded them of who they knew Him to be.  Then He left at will, disappearing.

To me this speaks to how He was fundamentally changed.
Once again, when we see Him, we shall be like Him.